# What Test Automation skills should a Engineer posses in 2021?

Tags: automated-testing, skillset, test-tools, test-engineering

I see Automation engineers learning  lot of tools like jenkins, docker,  cloud tools, Kubernates, git, vmware,  etc.

In 2021, what skills should a highly skilled Automation resource have to become a very important asset for any company?

What new trends we might see in the next  year?

Comment: Jimmy, your question will be closed because it is "opinion-based". I would suggest avoiding "best practice"-like questions for Stack Exchange, there are other forums for deeper discussions. This guide may help you to format your questions for Stack Exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**Testers' skills in high demand for 2021:**

(same as for 2020, 2019, 2018...)

- eye for detail
- general IT competence
- communication skills
- continuous learner